# How do you partition tables in BigQuery using DBT

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning, partition, dbt

I am new to DBT and have previously been using Airflow for data transformations.

In Airflow there is a variable called `{{ ds }}` which represents the logical date in this form `YYYY-MM-DD` and `{{ ds_nodash }}` which represents the logical date in this form `YYYYMMDD`. I can then set up a task similar this:

```
my_task = BigQueryOperator(
  task_id='t_my_task',
  sql= """ SELECT * FROM my_table where my_date="{{ ds }}" """,
  destination_dataset_table='my_project.my_dataset.my_table_new${{ ds_nodash }}',
  write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
  dag=dag
)
```

This means that I am running the SQL query given on the third line and this will overwrite the table on the fourth line. In the Airflow interface, if I rerun say just the day "2022-01-11" then it will automatically overwrite that partition on that date.

I am trying to figure out how to do the same in DBT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With DBT you can do that by using an [**incremental model**](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models#what-is-an-incremental-model).

In dbt, you describe the data you want with SQL statements, and the **materialization** you choose dictates the way it's going to be materialized in your warehouse:

- ephemeral materialization: a CTE that will be short-lived,
- table materialization: a BQ table, but everytime you re-run your DBT project it gets deleted and re-created (not suitable for big tables)
- view materializations: views...
- and incremental models

With incremental models you basically have a big table where you want to insert new rows. This materialization lets you add rules such as "insert rows from table `source_table` where timestamp >= today".

In your case, with DBT + BigQuery, you have 2 options: `merge` or `insert+ overwrite`, but from your description you'll want to use the latter.

You'll need to include this at the beginning of your model:

```
{{
  config(
    materialized='incremental',
    incremental_strategy='insert_overwrite',
    ...
  )
}}
```

For reference you can go [there](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/bigquery-configs#merge-behavior-incremental-models) and [there](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/bigquery-dbt-incremental-changes/982).

Comment: You can now do it in a more BigQuery fashion, see docs: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/bigquery-configs

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this behavior you need to define the following three configurations in your `dbt` model:

1. A partition column with `day` granularity
2. The incremental `inser_overwrite` strategy (that overwritten whole partitions)
3. The implementation of the incremental logic using `is_incremental()`

See a slightly adapted example take from [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/bigquery-configs#merge-behavior-incremental-models) below:

```
{{
 config(
   materialized = 'incremental',
   incremental_strategy = 'insert_overwrite',
   partition_by = {
     'field': 'session_start', 
     'data_type': 'timestamp'
     'granularity': 'day'
   }
 )
}}

with events as (

   select * from {{ref('events')}}

   {% if is_incremental() %}

    -- recalculate the latest day's data + previous
    where date(event_timestamp) >= date_sub(date(_dbt_max_partition), interval 1 day)

   {% endif %}

),

... rest of model ...
```